# calculating average depends of the number of variables of raw data in python

Tags: pandas

I am stuck on calculating the average depends on the variables in python.

I have 8 variables as below.

Case 1.

```
Time         df1    df2   df3   df4   df5   df6  df7   df8
2020-01-01   220    250   235   215   221   221  220   253
```

In this case I can just calculate average like below

```
  df['dfaverage']=(df['df1']+df['df2']+df['df3']+df['df4']+df['df5']+df['df6']+df['df7']+df['df8'])/8
```

The output will be 229.4

but if one of the value is zero then how would i ignore that values and calculate?
Case 2.

```
Time         df1    df2   df3   df4   df5   df6  df7   df8
2020-01-01   220    250   235   215   221   221  220    0
```

the output should be 226 for case2 but when I run the code I will get 197.8.
How can I ignore 0 when calculating the average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `0` to missing values and use `mean`:

```
df['dfaverage'] = df.replace(0, np.nan).mean(axis=1)

print (df)
       Time  df1  df2  df3  df4  df5  df6  df7  df8  dfaverage
0  2020-01-01  220  250  235  215  221  221  220    0      226.0
```

Or if need specify column names use `list`:

```
cols = [ 'df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5', 'df6', 'df7', 'df8']
df['dfaverage'] = df[cols].replace(0, np.nan).mean(axis=1)

print (df)
         Time  df1  df2  df3  df4  df5  df6  df7  df8  dfaverage
0  2020-01-01  220  250  235  215  221  221  220    0      226.0
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting KeyError:('df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5', 'df6', 'df7', 'df8'). any ideas? thank you

Comment: yes failed when runned cols = [ 'df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5', 'df6', 'df7', 'df8'] df['dfaverage'] = df[cols].replace(0, np.nan).mean(axis=1)

Comment: @EliSmith - Columns names are different?What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: when I run print(df.columns.tolist()), I get [' Time',' df1',' df2','df3', 'df4','df5',   'df6', 'df7',' df8']

Comment: @EliSmith - there is space before `' df1'` and similar for another values. Use `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` for remove it before my solution.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to put space in front of df1

Comment: can I ask you one more question? I am trying to calculate the average of my columns but number of columns can be 7 or 8 it changes every time.
How can I write a code to accept all the cases (works for even if number of columns are different every time)?

Comment: @EliSmith - If use first solution not working, because there are some another numeric columns which are excluded from mean?

Comment: Yes, I have cases that I can have columns up to df8 or df7, if I assign columns name and if that columns is absent that error happens. is there any way to calculate average when it has 7 columns and 8 columns?

Comment: @EliSmith - Try `df['dfaverage'] = df[df.columns.intersection(cols)].replace(0, np.nan).mean(axis=1)` - [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html)